# What's wrong with this remapping?

Tags: vim, vi

I want to define a mapping that takes the cursor to the end of the line and inserts a semicolon there. I have put this in the .vimrc file:

`inoremap aa <ESC>A;<ESC>`

it works fine in the `insert` mode but doesn't work in the `normal mode`!! Please explain why this is happening and what can be done so that it also works in the `normal mode`. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To make it work for normal mode also you need to add this mapping:

```
nnoremap aa A;<ESC>
```

---

- `inoremap` means **insert mode** mapping
- `vnoremap` means **visual mode** mapping
- `nnoremap` means **normal mode** mapping
- `cnoremap` means **command mode** mapping
- `noremap` means **visual, normal & Operator-pending** **modes** mapping

For others you can check them by executing `:help noremap`